# JSON and MultipartFile in POST Controller

Tags: spring-mvc, jackson

I have a controller method, which accepts a multipart post request, containing json and a binary file. It does it's job, but I would like to get rid of explicit `objectMapper.readValue()` call.

```
@PostMapping
public void createEmployee(@RequestParam("employee") String employee, 
                           @RequestParam("cv") MultipartFile cv
                          ) throws IOException {
    Employee empl = objectMapper.readValue(employee, Employee.class);
    service.createEmployee(empl, cv.getBytes());
}
```

I tried another way:

```
@PostMapping
public void createEmployee(@RequestPart("employee") Employee employee, 
                           @RequestPart("cv") MultipartFile cv
                          ) throws IOException {
    service.createEmployee(employee, cv.getBytes());
}
```

But here I got code 415: "Content type 'application/octet-stream' is not supported".

Answer (score 0):

Add consume in `PostMapping` annotation:

E.g.:

```
@PostMapping(consumes={"multipart/form-data"})
```

Comment: Tried this out, but nothing changed.